# How to add opacity to a parent div without applying it to children divs

Tags: html, css

I added `opacity` to a wrap I have that makes a background behind `input` fields I have. I was only wanting the wrap to have the `opacity`, but it gave it to all of the inputs as well. How can I apply the `opacity` only to the wrap around the inputs?

I made a fiddle to show somewhat how it looks.

https://jsfiddle.net/ajemyg8x/

I added the opacity to this `div`:

```
.registerWrap {
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 3px solid white;
    width: 45%;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 100px auto 40px auto;
    padding: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #282828;
    opacity: 0.9;
    filter: alpha(opacity=90); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

```css
#wrap {
  background-color: gray;
}
.registerWrap {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  width: 45%;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 100px auto 40px auto;
  padding: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #282828;
  opacity: 0.9;
  filter: alpha(opacity=90);
  /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
.inputbar[type=text] {
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.40s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.40s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.40s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.40s ease-in-out;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
}
.inputbar:hover {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
}
.inputbar[type=text]:focus {
  border: 1px solid #800000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(128, 0, 0, 1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(128, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(128, 0, 0, 1);
}
#registerButton[type=submit] {
  margin: 15px auto;
  width: 425px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #800000;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
#registerButton[type=submit]:hover {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="registerWrap">
    <form action="" method="POST">
      <input type="text" class="inputbar" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" required>
      <input type="text" class="inputbar" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" required>
      <input type="email" class="inputbaremail" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
      <input type="tel" class="inputbarphone" name="phone_number" placeholder="Cell Phone Number" required>
      <input type="text" class="inputbar" name="username" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off" required>
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="inputbarp" required>
      <input type="password" name="password_again" placeholder="Confirm Password" class="inputbarp" required>
      <label for="registerButton">
        <input id="registerButton" type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">
      </label>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: have you attempted `.registerWrap > * { opacity:1; }`

Comment: No, but just did and that didn't help.

Comment: I have updated your JS fiddle and posted an answer. Seems to work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could actually set a `rgba` color value for the `background-color` of the `wrap` like below. The value `rgba(40, 40, 40, 0.9)` is nothing but the `rgb` equivalent of your hex color `#282828` and the `opacity` that was added to the element.

One possible drawback is that `rgba` color values is [not supported by IE8 and lower](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-colors). If you need to support those browsers then this method is not for you.

```
.registerWrap {
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 3px solid white;
    width: 45%;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 100px auto 40px auto;
    padding: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(40, 40, 40, 0.9);
    /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

Here is a sample snippet with an image as the background for the wrap to make the effect more visible.

```css
#wrap {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/600/400);
}
.registerWrap {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  width: 45%;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 100px auto 40px auto;
  padding: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #282828;
  opacity: 0.9;
  filter: alpha(opacity=90);
  /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
.inputbar[type=text] {
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.40s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.40s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.40s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.40s ease-in-out;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
}
.inputbar:hover {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
}
.inputbar[type=text]:focus {
  border: 1px solid #800000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(128, 0, 0, 1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(128, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(128, 0, 0, 1);
}
#registerButton[type=submit] {
  margin: 15px auto;
  width: 425px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #800000;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
#registerButton[type=submit]:hover {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="registerWrap">
    <form action="" method="POST">
      <input type="text" class="inputbar" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" required>
      <input type="text" class="inputbar" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" required>
      <input type="email" class="inputbaremail" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
      <input type="tel" class="inputbarphone" name="phone_number" placeholder="Cell Phone Number" required>
      <input type="text" class="inputbar" name="username" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off" required>
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="inputbarp" required>
      <input type="password" name="password_again" placeholder="Confirm Password" class="inputbarp" required>
      <label for="registerButton">
        <input id="registerButton" type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">
      </label>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Paul: Glad to be of help pal :)

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your CSS ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ajemyg8x/1/)):

```
   #wrap {
        background-color: gray;
    }

    .registerWrap {
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: 3px solid white;
        width: 45%;
        height: 500px;
        margin: 100px auto 40px auto;
        padding: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #282828;
        opacity: 0.9;
        filter: alpha(opacity=90);
        /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
        .registerWrap * {
             opacity:1;   
        }
    .inputbar[type=text] {
        display: block;
        width: 400px;
        margin: 10px auto;
        font-size: 18px;
        padding: 10px;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.40s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.40s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all 0.40s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 0.40s ease-in-out;
        outline: none;
        border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    }
    .inputbar:hover {
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
    }
    .inputbar[type=text]:focus {
        border: 1px solid #800000;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(128, 0, 0, 1);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(128, 0, 0, 1);
        box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(128, 0, 0, 1);
    }
    #registerButton[type=submit] {
        margin: 15px auto;
        width: 425px;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 14px;
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: #800000;
        border: none;
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    #registerButton[type=submit]:hover {
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
    }
```

I have added:

```
.registerWrap * {
    opacity:1;   
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Setting opacity will affect all the child elements. Instead, you could just set the background color opacity, like so:

```
background-color: rgba(40, 40, 40, .9); /* last value is opacity */
```